# Question on limits and delta functions (Coming from work on Matsubara Green's functions and analytic continuation)

Tags: condensed-matter, mathematics, calculus, dirac-delta-distributions

I am working with condensed matter field theory with theory along the lines of Altland and Simon. I have some Matsubara Green's functions where I want to do analytic continuation and in that regard I run into some pretty fundamental questions on delta functions and limits.

Let's say I want to take the limit of:
$$\lim_{\eta\to 0}\frac{a-d+\eta^2}{(a-d)^2+d\eta^2},$$
and I naively look at this and say we get $\frac{1}{a-d}$. But then it turns out that $a-d = 0$ so that would diverge. But if $a-d=0$ before doing the limit I would have gotten:
$$\lim_{\eta\to0} \frac{\eta^2}{a\eta^2} = a^{-1}.$$

Could anyone explain to me how I am supposed to handle this? Often in physics we do the limits in some order, but in this case I am not sure what order? I guess first we do analytic continuation so $i\omega_n \to \omega + i\eta$ (to get retarded Greens function) and then look for poles afterwards, meaning in this example we do $a-d=0$ afterwards, or is there a deeper understanding of this?
This reminds me of the Lorentzian distribution which becomes the delta function after taking the limit, but in this case I am not sure.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: What are the domains of $a,d$? The expression is ill-defined for $a=0=d$. Consider to include what $a,d$ represent physically.

Comment: You've demonstrated that your function is not analytic, or even continuous, at $(\eta,a-d) = (0,0)$. In this case, the limits cannot be interchanged so you need to carefully go through the derivation to figure out what the correct order of limits are.

Comment: @Qmechanic In my case $a , d \in \mathbb{R}^+$ so I think it is well defined.  I guess my problem was more how to handle the order of limits in the case of wanting to find the poles of a retarded Greens function after analytic continuation

Comment: @SeanE.Lake I think you are correct. I am not sure about this exactly but I think the retarded Greens function is supposed to be analytic in the upper half of the complex plane so $eta \to 0$ is not something one HAS to do. $\eta$ comes from the analytic continuation so some $\omega_n \to \omega + i\eta$, so essentially when I take the limit of $eta \to 0$ I am actually brining to the function to the real plane where it is not analytic. In books like Altland and Simon they also dont really do the limit but just denote $\eta = 0^+$, so taking a limit might actually be wrong.

Comment: $\eta=0^+$ denotes a one-sided limit from above. What's the differential equation and what are the boundary conditions? That's what you're trying to satisfy, so the answer is, ultimately, going to be that the correct limit order is the order that satisfies those. Note: Green's functions solve the inhomogenous problem, so some of the boundary conditions come from that.

Comment: If $\eta$ is a regularization parameter you typically want to take its limit last.